# Arrays have incompatible sizes for the operation

Tags: matlab, redes-neuronales

Estoy entrenando una red multicapa a través de Matlab, y tengo el siguiente código:

```
clear ; close all; clc


P = xlsread('MatrizEntrenamiento.xlsx','P');
P = P'
Q = size(P, 2);

T = xlsread('MatrizEntrenamiento.xlsx','t');
T = T'

% Valores iniciales
n1 = 17; 
ep = 1;
W1 = ep*(2*rand(n1,63) - ep);
b1 = ep*(2*rand(n1,1) - ep);
W2 = ep*(2*rand(5,n1) - ep);
b2 = ep*(2*rand(5,1) - ep);

alfa = 0.01;
for Epocas = 1:600
    for i = 1:Q
        a1 = tg_sig(W1*P(:,i) + b1);
        a2 = tg_sig(W2*a1 + b2);
        e = T(:,i)-a2;
        s2 = -2*diag(1-a2.^2)*e;
        s1 = diag((1-a1.^2))*W2'*s2;
        W2 = W2 - alfa*s2*a1';
        b2 = b2 - alfa*s2;
        W1 = W1 - alfa*s1*P(:,i)';
        b1 = b1 - alfa*s1;  
        ec(i) = e'*e;
    end

    ecm(Epocas)= sum(ec)/Q;
    if mod(Epocas,50) == 0
        Epocas
        plot(ecm)
        pause(0.1)
    end
end

disp('valores para error medio')
disp(ecm)

figure, plot(a1)
figure, plot(a2)

%Verificación
for q=1:Q
    a1 = tg_sig(W1*P(:,q) + b1);
    [a iwin(q)] = max(W2*a1 + b2);
end
y = [1*ones(1,600)];
for i=2:10
    y = [y [i*ones(1,600)]];
end
NumeroAciertos = sum(y==iwin)
PorcentajeAciertos = NumeroAciertos/5000*100
```

Al correr el código, me aparece el siguiente error:

"Arrays have incompatible sizes for this operation.

Error in proyecto2 (line 121)

NumeroAciertos = sum(y==iwin)"

Estuve analizando bastante tiempo el código e intentando posibles soluciones, pero nunca logre llegar a solucionarlo, y me gustaria saber si alguien de esta comunidad me podría ayudar en ello.

Comment: P y T son valores añadidos a través de un archivo de Excel

Comment: A Q le asignas el Size de (P, 2) pero a no haces lo mismo con T. ¿Es sensible a Mayúsculas? Porque en P pones xlread('bla', 'P') pero en T pones la letra en minúscula

Comment: T la pongo en minuscula el xlread porque la pestaña esta escrita como 't'

Comment: verifica el tamaño de tus arreglos `y` y `iwin` para que puedas hacer `sum(y==iwin)`